# Odata web-api, How Filter apply on SQL View

Tags: odata, microsoft-odata

```
http://localhost:8085/odata/ViewItemHistories?$filter=SalesLineId eq 1 and SalesOrdno eq 'SO-00001' and SoLnStatus  eq 'Closed'
```

we have Odata V3 Configured Web Api and one of Table has Thousand of records
we have created SQL view so far and configured it in Odata, it is working well but I have a question

When I call ViewItemHistories view, it will get all the data, and after the filter is applied ?

or

filter will be applied first on ViewItemsHistory View and then data will be fetched ?

I tried to search but could not find any article about it